# Fastest way to find string in the array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose we have an array of strings, like this:

```
var arr = ['qwe', 'rty', 'uio p', 'a', 's df'];
```

but much longer. And a string, which is the user input.

So, on every `keyup` (next character inserted in that string) I have to check if this string is present in that array.

I know I can do it by looping through the array every time - but is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: `arr.indexOf(input) > -1`

Comment: With an array, you can't get better than linear. You need some sort of tree/table or other indexed data structure to go below `O(n)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the indexOf() function for that.

```
var arr = ['qwe', 'rty', 'uio p', 'a', 's df'];
var str= 'rty';

var isPresent = (arr.indexOf(str) > -1);
```

To explain:
indexOf() return the index of the string found in the array. If the string is not found, it returns -1.
So...indexOf('qwe') returns 0, indexOf('rty') returns 1, etc. But indexOf('foo') returns -1.

Comment: I think it's the best you got.

Comment: @k102: First, 'is it really fast?': [check for yourself: JSPerf.com](http://jsperf.com/); second, how fast do you really need it to be?

Comment: @DavidThomas as fast as it can be :) `indexOf` is a bit faster than a simple loop, so I thought if there's some better way.

Answer (score 2):

Use `IndexOf()`:

```
var arr = ['qwe', 'rty', 'uio p', 'a', 's df'];
arr.indexOf('a'); // returns 3
arr.indexOf('aaa'); // returns -1
```